# CardView doesn't expand properly

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, cardview

[card screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb2rQ.png)

I have a TimerView class that extends CardView. It's initially collapsed to show only the first line and it expands on tap. The problem is that it doesn't expand as much as it should. In the screenshot you can see that the bottom image is smaller than the others but the resolutions of the three images are all the same.

Here is the code that makes it expand. The clicked variable is static and I use it to measure the height of the card just one time because all the cards are the same.

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate(){
    super.onFinishInflate();

    RelativeLayout upperCard = findViewById(R.id.upper_card);

    upperCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                LinearLayout subCard = findViewById(R.id.sub_card);

                if(!clicked){
                    foldedHeight = getMeasuredHeightAndState();
                    subCard.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    targetHeight = foldedHeight + subCard.getMeasuredHeightAndState();
                    clicked = true;
                }

                if(subCard.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    subCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ImageView arrow = findViewById(R.id.arrow);
                    arrow.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp));
                    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(foldedHeight, targetHeight);
                    valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
                    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                            requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                    valueAnimator.start();
                }
...
```

And this is the xml file related to TimerView.

```
<com.whatever.marco272.timepassedsince.TimerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:contentPadding="7dp"
card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/upper_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sub_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="0" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Update"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/edit_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Edit"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Delete"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with the `CardView`'s padding. On pre-Lollipop API levels, `CardView` overwrites whatever padding you've set in order to inset the card (so that it can draw the "shadow" inside the view's bounds). Since you've set the `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` attribute, this will *also* happen for you on Lollipop and above.

I believe that this padding accounts for the "missing" height when you expand.

Comment: Without this line it works as expected but I want this card appearence and if I'm not mistaken it makes the design consistent between API levels. By the way I added `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"` and it seems to work fine. Could this be a solution?